# invalid cast. Viewstate and gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net

I stumbled upon an error in my code that I can't figure out. Here is the code in question:

```
int indexToSave = -1;
const string EDIT = "edit";
if (ViewState[EDIT] != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gvSensorList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((string)ViewState[EDIT]) == (string)gvList.Rows[i].ClientID)
        {
            indexToSave = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The line that throws the exception is `if(((string)ViewState[EDIT] == (string)gvList.Rows[i].ClientID)`. The exception I get is `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'` but as far as I can tell,  I dont cast any int to string?

Comment: What is the value of `gvList.Rows[i].ClientID` exactly when you debug your code?

Comment: @SonerGönül `"ctl00_body_gvList_ctl02"`, So it's a string

Comment: Hmm, then you get this exception on `ViewState[EDIT]`  part. What is the value of `ViewState[EDIT]` exactly?

Comment: apparently that was my problem :S I tried to write a trace just to see what it contains, but I got the error there instead. The sollution that astian suggested solved it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `if ((ViewState[EDIT].ToString()) == gvList.Rows[i].ClientID.ToString())` ?

Comment: It worked when I changed `((string)ViewState[EDIT])` to `(ViewState[EDIT].ToString())`. Do you know why it is like this? I've allways used `((string)ViewState[EDIT])` and I have never gotten this problem before :S

Comment: Im not sure but I think that int cant be explicitly casted to string. You will have to reasearch that, but because of similar problems I try using the .ToString() method for each casting to string.